# Transparency not working in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transparency

I have Blender 2.75 and I am working on a project. I want to import a transparent window texture but when I do this happens:

[image: untransparent]

It doesn't look transparent in Blender. When I render it with a light and a green cube behind it this happens:

[image: untransparent background]

The bars are transparent but the background turned black. The same thing happens with another texture when I import it. The background of the texture is white and doesn't blend in with the brick texture:

[image: cage]

How do I make these textures transparent the right way?

EDIT: When I add this node setup:

[image: node setup]

The 3rd texture (with the background not blending in) just shows all white and it's a black border when rendered.

[image: white texture]

Comment: What is your node setup for the bars?

Comment: I think you do not have any alpha information in your black and white images. Try simple plugging the color socket in to the *Fac* of the mix node.

Answer (score 3):

There is no alpha channel behind the bars, just around the window.

This image shows the alpha channel you have on your image.
To make it transparent use the following node setup:

[image]

To make the black areas of the images transparent you need to edit the image on an image editor (like photoshop or gimp), or add acolor ramp to control the transparency on a new mix shader.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In cycles the proper way to use a texture with transparency is to mix a diffuse shader (or whatever shader[s] you are using for your material) with a transparent shader based on the *alpha* output of the *image texture* node.

[image]

Comment: @KalebProvost  What does your node setup look like?

Comment: The 3rd picture texture (with the background not blending in) doesn't show when I use the node settings.

Comment: @KalebProvost It's kind of hard to tell exactly what you're doing wrong without seeing a few more details of what you are doing.  Would it be possible to post some more screenshots or upload your .blend to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: I edited the question to include my node setup. It works for the bars but not the last texture.

Comment: @KalebProvost  Does the bars texture have an alpha texture?

Comment: both of them do.

Comment: @KalebProvost  Would it be possible to upload the texture you are using?

Comment: http://imgur.com/UKHkCKV Here it is.